# Popup menu appears blank

Tags: java, android, popupmenu

I am working on an app, in which I am want to use a pop-up menu to control some actions and settings. However, when I launch the app in my emulator, the items appear blank, although when I click on them, the action is fired and it works. Here is a screen of the emulator:

[image]

I am following the guide, so my code does not differ much from the dev guides, but here is my code:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long ID)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            courseId = ID;
            fields = sqldbase.query(DBHelper.courseTable, new String[] {
                    DBHelper.courseID, DBHelper.courseName,
                    DBHelper.courseProf, DBHelper.averageGrade },
                    DBHelper.courseID + " = " + ID, null, null, null, null);

            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getBaseContext(), view);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.courses_popup_menu,
                    popup.getMenu());   
            popup.show();
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item)
                {
                         Log.i(TAG,"OnMenuItemClick Fired");                                                             return false;

                }

            });

            return false;
        }

    });
```

Could this be related to a problem with themes? I have been trying to use a Holo.light.NoTitleBar theme, so in my xml in eclipse, the word `Passbook` does not show, and everything is white, instead of black. However, after running in the emulator, the theme is ignored, and this shows up.

Thanks.

Comment: What API level is your emulator running on?

Comment: The latest(17). I am not using any support.v4 packages in my app either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it. apparently, popup menus use the attribute android:title instead of android:text.